# Matrix operation to switch last shape of tensor in keras

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Is there any method to output like this?

```
x = (30, 64, 36, 1)
y = (30, 64, 36, 2048)
```

Is there some operation that can make the output of shape (30, 64, 2048, 1) with x and y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I Understand Correctly (IIUC) you want this:

[image]

You can use `einsum` in `numpy` or `tensorflow` like below:

**Numpy Version**

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(30, 64, 36, 1)
y = np.random.rand(30, 64, 36, 2048)
z = np.einsum('ijkl,ijkm->ijml', x, y)
# output[i,j,m,l] = sum_k x[i,j,k,l] * y[i,j,k,m]
print(z.shape)
```

**Tensorflow Version**

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.random.normal(shape=[30, 64, 36, 1])
y = tf.random.normal(shape=[30, 64, 36, 2048])
z = tf.einsum('ijkl,ijkm->ijml', x, y)
# output[i,j,m,l] = sum_k x[i,j,k,l] * y[i,j,k,m]
print(z.shape)
```

Output:

```
(30, 64, 2048, 1)
```

Comment: Wow, that is exactly what I want.
Is there any method that I can think the output and input shape in matrix operation?

Comment: @puhuk, I don't understand your question. Do you want another method?

Comment: No, I just ask how do you think about the method so fast. Because I can not ask whenever I have question with operation shape.

Comment: @puhuk, thanks, I read and learn before and when you ask I think this will be best answer for you. for reading about einsum you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum),  or about see different performance and how is fast you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72489466/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deal-with-a-loop-on-numpy-arrays).